# Manually Upgrading React Native Version Expo Eject

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, upgrade

I'm modestly trying to upgrade from React Native 0.64.3 to 0.65.0.

At first I tried to follow straight React Native procedure using React Native Helper:
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.3&to=0.65.0

The instructions in the Helper clearly does not fully apply to Expo Eject projects, as, for instance, it tells you to use LaunchScreen.storyboard instead of SplashScreen.storyboard in the project.phxproj file in the iOS folder.

If I follow Expo's suggestions: https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-45-f4e332954a68
Command `expo upgrade 45` takes my app straight to `react-native 0.68.2`
Then Expo tells you to use the Helper to 'apply relevant changes'. I have a tough time deciding what is relevant and what isn't.

And if I look at RN Upgrade Helper's instructions, the new modified files don't seem to make any reference to expo. It obviously doesn't seem right.

I certainly would like to just use the copy and paste the modified files for files like project.phxproj with tons of edts, instead of removing the red lines and adding the green lines line by line.

In the end, I can't trust the instructions on RN Upgrade Helper for Expo eject apps. If you have any insight into this, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upgrade to 0.65.0. Here are a couple of tips for upgrading React-Native projects that might help others in the future:

1. do not upgrade Expo
2. do not edit the project.phx.proj file, and probably not any of the files that the RNUH has initially closed on their 'accordion' of instructions. I will update as I get more experience
3. remember to `pod update` and `pod install`
4. remember to `npx react-native start --reset-cache` to build your app after you have done everything.